# git rebase randomly need to be run twice

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm facing a weird bug on my git bash for windows since the year has started: I randomly have some commands like `git rebase` that seem to skip a parameter once or twice and need to be run multiple times before actually doing what I want.
Example:

```
02:56:30 (release/1.21.0) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ git rebase develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: C1
Applying: C2
Applying: C3
Applying: C4
[1]-  Done                    gitk --all
[2]+  Done                    gitk --all
02:57:15 (release/1.21.0) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ gitk --all &
[1] 18652
```

At this point no rebase on develop occured, release/1.21.0 was still where it used to be.

```
02:57:16 (release/1.21.0) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ git rebase develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: C1
Applying: C2
Applying: C3
Applying: C4
[1]+  Done                    gitk --all
02:57:22 (release/1.21.0) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ git rebase develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: C1
.git/rebase-apply/patch:10: trailing whitespace.
#if DEBUG
.git/rebase-apply/patch:11: trailing whitespace.
            String errorMessage = "YY";
.git/rebase-apply/patch:12: trailing whitespace.
#else
.git/rebase-apply/patch:13: trailing whitespace.
            String errorMessage = "XX";
.git/rebase-apply/patch:14: trailing whitespace.
#endif
warning: squelched 36 whitespace errors
warning: 41 lines add whitespace errors.
Resolved 'X/Properties/PublishProfiles/Integration.pubxml' using previous resolution.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       X/Application/Controllers/A.cs
M       XTests/Application/Controllers/ATests.cs
M       X/App_Start/B.cs
A       X/Properties/PublishProfiles/A.pubxml
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging X/Properties/PublishProfiles/B.pubxml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in X/Properties/PublishProfiles/B.pubxml
Auto-merging X/App_Start/A.cs
Auto-merging XTests/Application/Controllers/ATests.cs
Auto-merging X/Application/Controllers/B.cs
Patch failed at 0001 C1
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

I needed to do two more `git rebase develop` so it would actually do the rebase **on develop**

I have the same example with `git rebase --skip`:

```
03:04:51 (release/1.21.0|REBASE 6/8) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ git rebase --skip
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>] [<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] --root [<branch>]
   or: git-rebase --continue | --abort | --skip | --edit-todo

Available options are
   [...]
03:04:56 (release/1.21.0|REBASE 6/8) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ git rebase --skip
Applying: C1
Applying: C2
[...]
```

**EDIT**: My aliases are

```
08:40:23 (integration) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ alias
alias apilog='api_server_log'
alias extlog='extranet_log'
alias gd='git diff --word-diff'
alias gf='git fetch --prune'
alias gk='gitk --all &'
alias gs='git status'
alias gt='git tree -n 15'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias lsf='lsfull'
alias lsg='lsgit'
alias lsp='lspacks'
alias reload='source ~/.bashrc'
alias vs='start *.sln'
alias winenv='rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables'
```

and no git-rebase is found by which:

```
08:40:35 (integration) /d/Repositories/Git/X $ which git-rebase
which: no git-rebase in ([...])
```

What is going on?? Did I wreck my config somehow, and how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Does this only happen with `git`?  Can you reproduce with another program, say `echo`?

Comment: I edited the title, at the moment it seems only `git rebase` is affected

Comment: This is very strange.  What happens when you run it from the Windows command line instead of git bash?  Does `alias git` show any output?  Can you run `which git-rebase` (note the dash) and is there any output?

Comment: I checked my aliases as well as my ~/.gitconfig, nothing funny looking but i'll put it here tomorrow to be sure. I haven't tried from windows command prompt but I might not have that ability set up

Comment: @EdwardThomson I added the aliases and the output of which